# Criteria in favor of AppBundle

Tags: android, google-play, android-app-bundle

Google Play is not the first time insistently offers to use the [App Bundle](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle) application.

I started to understand, but did not see many criteria and reasons to use it in my project, so please tell me who has already encountered or managed to notice more than me.

One of the main criteria that I managed to identify for myself is the ability to load functions **On Demand**. By the way which are very well described [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/on-demand-dynamic-delivery/index.html#0).

But based on this, the only criterion that comes to my mind is that you can load those or modules as needed.

It is also not clear how the choice of screen extensions/specific platform when downloading the application from the Google Play Store.

Answer (score 3):

App Bundle allows your app to be split up along different lines.

https://developer.android.com/platform/technology/app-bundle

> It's easy to switch. You don't need to refactor your code to start benefiting from a smaller app. And once you've switched, you'll benefit from modular app development and customizable feature delivery.

Therefore like you mention

> One of the main criteria that I managed to identify for myself is the ability to load functions On Demand. By the way which are very well described here.

So Google can be clever and send a subset of your app to the device. (The benefit being **faster download times** for your app. **More acquisition**, **less user drop off** on install).

If your app targets tablets and phones, google can be clever and only send the tablet resources to the tablet. Same example can be said for languages and other resource types.

Documentation benefits:

They give 6

TLDR: 1 file to upload when making an app

> Build one artifact that includes all of your app's compiled code, resources, and native libraries for your app. You no longer need to build, sign, upload, and manage version codes for multiple APKs.

---

TLDR: smaller downloads for users

> Google Play's Dynamic Delivery uses your Android App Bundle to build and serve APKs that are optimized for each device configuration. This means your users enjoy a smaller app download without the unused code and resources needed for other devices. Track the size of your app in the new app size report in the Google Play Console.

---

TLDR: smaller downloads for users

> Customize and control your user experience by delivering features to the devices and users you choose, as and when they're needed, instead of at install time. This means that adding features no longer has to result in adding to your app's size at install time. Use conditional delivery to deliver features to countries, device types, or devices running a minimum SDK version. Use on-demand delivery to deliver features on demand, which can be installed and uninstalled as needed.

---

TLDR: More maintainable code

> The Android App Bundle enables modular app development so you can design, build, debug and test your app's features as independent modules that can be added to your main app when ready. You'll see fewer merge conflicts and disruptions because you no longer have to have an entire engineering team working on the same monolithic app with complex and bloated code.

---

TLDR: Faster build speeds

> Build systems, such as the Android Studio build system using Gradle, are optimized for modular apps so they are significantly faster to build than large, monolithic apps. You'll spend less time sitting around waiting and more time designing, coding, and testing your app.

---

TLDR: Better user acquisition

> Instant-enable your Android App Bundle or instant-enable specific dynamic feature modules to give users a frictionless way to experience your app. Users can launch your experience from the Try Now button on Google Play and web links without installation.

Comment: Great summary. I think overall, the idea is "Focus on the business side of your app and let Google focus on lower-level optimizations". Also, publishing an App Bundle will give you more insights for your app in the Play Console (recently announced the "App Size" page with size optimization tips for developers publishing App Bundles). And as Blundell mentioned, the switch should be super easy.